# Python - numpy 2D array too long and prints weird?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I want to print a 2D array (shape of a square) to see it in my python panel, the format of the array appears to show up weird. It seems that 19 elements won't make a square shape, and puts that last element onto the next line. When I try with 18 elements, it's fine. I'm not sure if this is a numpy issue or my platform (I use Enthought Canopy). Is there anything I could do to have all 19 elements in one line when I print it out?

```
import numpy

a = numpy.zeros(361)
b = a.reshape(19,19)
print b
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.]]
```

Comment: Have you tried making your window a bit wider?

Comment: Well, the funny thing is that the window is maximized and half of the panel is just empty space that's available. I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: Tested it on my own machine. It's not a window width issue; the strings NumPy generates just have line breaks at those positions.

Comment: Perhaps something in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html will help?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I just didn't know what to search exactly on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the default line-wrapping width with [np.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). The default is 75.

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
```